# Backgrond service not affecting http session timeout

Tags: java, html, servlet-3.0

I need to create HTTP service called periodically using JavaScript in background.

Each call must not affect session timeout (session clock feature).

Is it possible? How should it be done in reliable way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it with help of [Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/).
Session expiration *deadline* is stored inside session and updated by http requests. Those with **stateless** parameter aren't update expiration timeout. 
Here is my code:

```
public class SessionTimeoutFilter implements Filter {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionTimeoutFilter.class);

/** The http stateless request parameter name. */
private final static String PAR_HTTP_STATELESS_REQUEST = "stateless";

/** The session expiry time argument name. */
private final static String ARG_SESSION_EXPIRY_TIME = "sessionExpiryTime";

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        if (httpReq.getParameterMap().containsKey(PAR_HTTP_STATELESS_REQUEST)) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            HttpSession session = httpReq.getSession(false);
            if (session != null) {
                Object expirationTime = session.getAttribute(ARG_SESSION_EXPIRY_TIME);

                if (expirationTime != null && expirationTime instanceof Long) {
                    Long expirationDate = (Long) expirationTime;

                    if (expirationDate < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                        // manual expiration
                        session.invalidate();
                        session = null;
                    }
                } 

                // session still active
                if (session != null) {
                    long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long expiryTime = currTime + session.getMaxInactiveInterval() * 1000;

                    // new expiration deadline
                    session.setAttribute(ARG_SESSION_EXPIRY_TIME, new Long(expiryTime));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Unable set session timeout cookies due to: " + e, e);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {}
```

}